# Replace permatreated 4x4 Hand rail post on step where concrete holding it has cracked?

Tags: concrete, post, pressure-treated

I bought a home 8 months ago where the deck handrail was planted at the edge of a concrete step as a 4x4 on the bottom step. The concrete at the edge of the step has cracked, the hand rail is wobbly, and has been fixed again (with some concrete repair mix) and has failed again. The concrete has cracked and been replaced. What would you recommend to fix it?

[image: Steps with rail and cracked base]

Answer (score 1):

I'd remove the wooden post, do a full repair of the broken step, and install a bolt-on steel or aluminum post with a vinyl cover on the step below.

Of course, this requires a rebuild of your rail assembly to extend it, but it should be full-length anyway.

Comment: isherwood, you are probably right, was hoping for something easier.

Answer (score 0):

It looks like it has been repaired before but not correctly. Without putting my eyes on it of course I would go the route mentioned in earlier post.
However if looking to save money you could also drill 1/2" holes insert 1/4 rebar after you fill it with liquid nail.
Clean any excess immediately.
Then simply reparge all the steps. You would have to drill to old concrete for it to work.

Good luck it's going to take a little muscle. Also if the old job used weak concrete it might need to be replaced as stated before.